# how to do a curl post request from https client in php for restfull api calling

Tags: php, curl

i am making a curl post request to call a restfull api from https client. it fails every time. However i am able to do successful curl post request if client is http and server is https by just setting 2 more parameters CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST.

But it always fails if client is https..
Code is given below:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_URL =>'https://103.253.36.41/bankAPI/recipient.php',
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request',
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST =>0,
CURLOPT_POST => 1,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
    recipient_id =>'1172',
    bankifsc => '',
    accountno => '',
    branch_name => '',
    branch_code => '',
    method=>'find'
)
));$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Any Help is much appreciated..

Comment: Your code works fine for me. You are correct in setting both verifypeer and verifyhost to false. Can you `var_dump($curl_response);` to see the output?

Comment: it returns false...as it is not hitting the url. it is just working fine if i am doing it from my local...or requesting from any http..issue come if i am initiating it from https server.

Comment: do you have port 443 open for outbound connections?

Comment: haha just checking. I'm really not sure then, like I said, this code worked fine for me using https.

Answer (score 0):

`http and https` are protocols in which client and server talk to each other - either both are http or https - it cannot be http-https combination

If server supports both http as well as https it will automatically choose the right one depending on URL (http:// or https://)

So, if your url contains https than use

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST.
```

if not than they are not required or will be ignored by curl